# Selenium WebDriver / Cucumber Tests are not getting executed when tried to run Maven Project

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, maven-3

I was trying to run maven project for my automation script using selenium/java. However, the tests are not getting run when I executed mvn test command. Please let me know what could be the issue that the cucumber tests are not getting executed when I try to run maven Project.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< KSAEpic3MavenProj:KSAEpic3 >---------------------
[INFO] Building KSAEpic3 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ KSAEpic3 -
--
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ KSAEpic3 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ KS
AEpic3 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ KSAEpic
3 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ KSAEpic3 ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.628 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-26T08:57:14+04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Below is my POM.XML file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>KSAEpic3MavenProj</groupId>
  <artifactId>KSAEpic3</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>KSAEpic3</name>

  <dependencies> 
 <dependency> 
 <groupId>junit</groupId> 
 <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
 <version>4.12</version> 
 <scope>test</scope> </dependency> 

 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId> 
 <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
 <version>2.53.0</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
 <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
 <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.4</version> 
 <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency> 

 <dependency> 
 <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> 
 <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId> 
 <version>1.2.4</version>
 <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency> 

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.23</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>ojdbc14</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>

</dependency>

 </dependencies> 


</project>
```

Log when run from IDE -

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building KSAEpic3 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ KSAEpic3 ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ KSAEpic3 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ KSAEpic3 ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ KSAEpic3 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ KSAEpic3 ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\Maven WorkSpace\KSAEpic3\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.751s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jul 26 09:41:48 GST 2018
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/19M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Runner Class

```
package testrunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(

        plugin={"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/JSON/Output.json"},      
                features={"D:/KSA-Online Banking-AutomationFramework/Epic2Maven/src/test/resources/features"},

//      plugin={"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:"},
tags={"@SI_TransferBtwAccounts"},

        glue={"stepdefinition"}

        )

public class Epic2TestRunner {

}
```

Feature File -

```
@SI_TransferBtwAccounts
Feature: Verify that SI is setup successfully Between the accounts and record is inserted in DB
Scenario: Verify that SI is setup successfully between the accounts
Given When browser is launched and KSA URL is loaded
    When STAFFUser1 logins to application
    When Password is entered
    When clicked on Login button
    When clicks on Pay&Transfer Icon
    When clicks on Transfer link
    When clicks on StandingInstruction link
     When selects TransferBtwAccount option
      When enters Trnsfrbtwaccamount in the field
    When FromandToDate are captured
       When Terms&Conditions are checked
    When clicked on continue button
       When StartandEnd Dates are verified in pre-confirmation screen
    When Entered OTP
    When clicked on Confirm button
    When Captured the Reference number
    When Record is displayed in StandingInstruction DB
    When record is displayed in the Standing Instruction menu
    Then user should be logged out of application.
```

StepDefinition file -

```
public class Transfer_SI_BtwAccounts  extends Browser_Initialization {

    private static String FromDate , ToDate, SIRefnum, refnumber, PurposeofTransferText, amount;

    @When("^STAFFUser(\\d+) logins to application$")
    public void staffuser_logins_to_application(int arg1) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
try {

            c_InputText("KSAOnlineBanking_Login_Username", GetPropertValue("StaffUssername"));

        } catch (Exception e ) {
            Assert.fail("unable to enter username"); 

        }
    }

    @When("^selects TransferBtwAccount option$")
    public void selects_TransferBtwAccount_option() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
       try {

           Thread.sleep(10000);

            c_click("TransferList");

            c_click("SI-BTWACC");

       } catch (Exception e ) {
           Assert.fail("unable to select option");
       }
    }

    @When("^enters Trnsfrbtwaccamount in the field$")
    public void enters_Trnsfrbtwaccamount_in_the_field() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
      try {
          Thread.sleep(6000);

          c_InputText("TBTWACCAmountField",GetPropertValue("EnterAmount"));

      } catch (Exception e ) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to run them through IDE?

Comment: No not from IDE also. please see edited log from IDE.

Comment: could you share the runner class?

Comment: I have shared the runner class. please see above. Thnx

Comment: You should not be using absolute path for features, instead you can just use `features={"src/test/resources/features"}`. Anyway it has nothing to do with the current issue. Could you share the one of the step definition and feature file, before that please make sure that `@SI_TransferBtwAccounts` in step definition is exactly same as the one in feature files.

Comment: I have shared one feature file and StepDefinition file. Please look at the edited version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176767/discussion-between-mahipal-and-aditya).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the test class is important, if not specified explicitely.

By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the [following wildcard patterns:](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)

> "**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "Test".
>   "**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
>   "**/*Tests.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Tests".
>   "**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".

Your class is named `Epic2TestRunner.java` so it is not recognized by default. Renaming it to `TestEpic2Runner.java` or `Epic2RunnerTest.java` would be a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks @SubOptimal Changing the name to TestEpic2Runner.java solved my issue. Thanks again